# max-min optimization problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization

I'm curious if there is any nice way to approach solving the following kind of optimization problem. Given a $n \times m$ matrix $A = (a_{ij})$, I want to solve
\begin{align*}
& \max_{c}\min_{1 \leq i \leq n} \left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j}a_{ij}\right|\\
& \textrm{ s.t. } \sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j} = 1, \quad c_{j} \geq 0.
\end{align*}

On a related note, if instead we have a vector of smooth scalar functions $\mathbf{f}(x) = [f_{1}(x), \ldots, f_{m}(x)]$ with each defined on some compact set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, is there a nice way to solve
\begin{align*}
& \max_{c} \min_{x \in X} \left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j}f_{j}(x) \right|\\
& \textrm{ s.t. } \sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j} = 1, \quad c_{j} \geq 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a slack variable t, as mentioned in Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd
\begin{align*}
& \max_{R} t \\
& \textrm{ s.t. } \left|\sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j}a_{ij}\right| \geq t \forall i\\
&  \sum_{j=1}^{m}c_{j} = 1, \quad c_{j} \geq 0
\end{align*}

Its a reduced linear programming problem. Geometrically, interpret it as maximizing the lower bound